# SQLServer 2012: Split String by delimiter in Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the following legacy code inside a stored proc...

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_Proc]     
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here    
   @ProductId int = 0,     
   @Attributes varchar(8000)
   ...
   DECLARE Attribute_Cursor CURSOR FOR    
     select [value] from SC_Splitter(@Attributes,',');
```

However, it says SC_Splitter is undeclared. Is there another way I can accomplish this?

Comment: There's never been, nor is there currently, a function built into SQL Server to split a string by delimiters. So, whatever `SC_Splitter` is, it's not part of SQL Server - you need to go and find out where it came from.

Comment: I understand but the functionality is pretty straight forward, it just splits the string. That is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql